# How to make a Timer exactly 30 seconds from created date Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to make an operation only available in 30 seconds, and then it expires. I Have this model:

(operation)

```
status = CharField(max_length=10, default="INI")
created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
account = ForeignKey(Account, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE)
metadata = models.JSONField(default=dict)
external_ref = CharField(max_length=128)
expires_at = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()+timezone.timedelta(seconds=30))
```

I wanna be able to create in the expires_at field, a timestamp with exactly 30 seconds from the created_at Date, it is like a timeout function, but when I run the test:

```
    def test_timeout_is_30_seconds(self):
        print(self.operation.created_at)
        timer = self.operation.created_at + timezone.timedelta(seconds=30)
        print(timer)
        self.assertEqual(self.operation.expires_at, timer)
```

it fails with this message:

```
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 19, 0, 42, 537490, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 19, 0, 45, 844588, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I dont know if I need to make an external function or method inside the class or directly in the View, but I would prefer this default behavior in the models so I dont need to worry about setting expiry dates

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve it! :D any tips and information is appreciated

Comment: Even without the additional field: `if datetime.now() - created_at <= timedelta(seconds=30):` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common error. Your expression `timezone.now()+timezone.timedelta(seconds=30)` is being evaluated once, when the class is defined, and that value is being used as the default for every instance.

What you actually want is for the expiration time to be freshly calculated each time a new instance is created. Which means that you want to set `default` to a function:

```
def half_minute_hence():
   return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(seconds=30)

expires_at = DateTimeField(default=half_minute_hence)
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin! two short questions, if you mind:

1. I did that function but with a variable:
```
time = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(seconds=30)
return time
```
Is it the same? Why can you return that instead of one result?

2.
```
expires_at = DateTimeField(default=half_minute_hence())
```
Why not that way? I do not understand when the parenthesis goes and when it does not

Comment: @MartinParadiso: 1) Yes, it is the same. 2) Using parentheses causes a function to be called. But you don't want to call the function now, you want to pass it as an argument to Django so it can be called later when the object is created. `half_minute_hence` is a function. `half_minute_hence()` is a specific `datetime`, and if you pass it as the `default` it will be the same one for all your objects.